# Spell checker suggestions does not appears in context menu

Tags: google-chrome, opera

In Opera and Google Chrome, when there is a typo, placing caret on the incorrect word and pressing context-menu key on keyboard does not show suggestions and I have to right click by mouse. Is it a bug?

Comment: I am not looking for "Spell Checker Options"!! The word suggestion for the falsy word is only showed by right click.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, see the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=282598).

Its fixed in the build `35.0.1870.2 dev-m`